# Axios related error when building react app using vite

Tags: reactjs, npm, axios, vite

Axios was working perfectly in production but when building the application, it results in this error.

```
> react-app@0.0.0 build
> vite build

vite v4.4.7 building for production...
✓ 118 modules transformed.
✓ built in 1.88s
[commonjs--resolver] Unexpected token (714:2) in C:/Users/application/client/node_modules/axios/lib/utils.js
file: C:/Users/application/client/node_modules/axios/lib/utils.js:714:2
712:   toFiniteNumber,
713:   findKey,
714:   {}: _global,
       ^
715:   isContextDefined,
716:   ALPHABET,
error during build:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (714:2) in C:/Users/application/client/node_modules/axios/lib/utils.js
    at pp$4.raise
```

Tried update npm, deleted node modules and installed dependencies again and updated all dependencies including axios

Answer (score 5):

Try adding

```
define: { _global: ({}), }
```

in your vite.config.js. This should define your global object as an empty new object.

This section of the vite config file performs a search and replace and your builder seems to struggle with finding what `_global` is in your project (I assume this can be window, the `global` node object etc, since `axios` is a library that works both in the browser and on the server)

Alternatively removing the `_global` definition in your `vite.config` file could also solve your issue, depending on your build target. I don't have enough information to help you further and these are just my assumptions from looking at your error. Providing your vite config node version etc. might be useful.

Comment: Omg thank you, that fixed it for me! This was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

I have defined

> define: { global: 'globalThis'}

and after that it works fine. It works locally and in production. "define: { _global: ({}), }", this only work for production but not for development. and "define: { global: ({}), }" this works for local but not for production. so the following solution works for both.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
   plugins: [react()],
   define: { global: 'globalThis'}  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced this problem today(react 18.2/react-admin 4.16.9/vite 4.2)
The changes for `vite.config` were not enough. The build began to be created without errors, but when starting the application an error began to appear: `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined`

So I added a `global` variable to the index.html

```
    <script>var global = global || window; </script>
```